# Upload script add's dots in array by default

Tags: php, arrays, upload

Trying to make a uploads correct. But when using var_dump on my upload folder there are two dots by default ['.', '..'] . What could be causing this ?

```
<?php
$render = '';
$filenames = '';
$dir = './upload';
$aFilenames = scandir($dir);

    if(isset($_FILES["file"]["error"]) > 1){
        echo "Error: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br />";

    } elseif (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$filename);

        $render .= "name file: " .$_FILES['file']['name'] .'<br>';
        $render .= "type file: " .$_FILES['file']['type'] .'<br>';
        $render .= "size: " .($_FILES['file']['size']/1024) .'kb <br>';
        $render .= "saved in: " .$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] .'<br>';
        $render .= '<img src="upload/'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'" height="40px">';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Upload a file';
    }
foreach ($aFilenames as $key) {
        $filenames .= $key . '<br>';
}
var_dump($aFilenames);

?>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the `parent directory` and the `previous directory`

You can see this behavior also, when you do a simple directory structure listing in cmd:

```
C:\data>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CEAE-5F97

 Directory of C:\data

12.01.2017  17:02              .
12.01.2017  17:02              ..
27.12.2016  11:10              db
08.12.2016  14:46              keys
01.12.2016  11:08           531 368 putty.exe
11.01.2017  13:00              www
               1 File(s)        531 368 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  133 482 266 624 bytes free
```

You can just unset those values, when using directory scans.